# Is it possible to call facebook Graph API using just REST calls through HTTP on iOS or android?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

Was wondering if it would be possible to call rest calls through facebook graph API using the device HTTP client using REST rather than calling it through facebook SDK?

I am doing this rest calls since I have a library that will provide the service for both platform. And I want to generalize this using REST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to make rest call from `android` or `IOS`. In your case as facebook graph api offers a rest api, you can.
Here is the [facebook graph api documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/quickstart/v2.2?locale=fr_FR).

Here an example i found on [facebook api documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/quickstart/v2.2?locale=fr_FR#step2) site

To pass the access token you could pass it in url :

```
POST graph.facebook.com
  /me/feed?
    message="Hello, World."&
    access_token={your-access-token}
```

Comment: just curious, how would you pass the access token? as a header? or within the urls?